# How can i solve error : click for price

Tags: magento-1.9, error, price

Actually i am imported Bulk products with **price**, after go to front end i faced error like  **click for price**, how can i solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you have "MSRP" field set for the product. MSRP (MAP) price display is disabled by default. You can disble the MAP(Minimum Advertised Price) display by going to `System > Configuration > Sales > Minimum Advertised Price` section. There, you will need to set `Enable MAP` to `No`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to go `Catalog` > `Manage Products` grid, and update the product attributes in steps of 100 or 200. Be sure to change the Indexing to [Manual](https://briansnelson.com/Turn_on_Manual_Indexing) mode as this will speed the product saving.